# Скиншот контрола panel

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Цель: сделать снимок контрола в частности панели(Mainpanel)
Проблема: удается сделать снимок только видимой области контрола
А нужна картинка всего содержимого для создания общей миниатюры

Использую следующий код

```
Bitmap memoryImage;
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
rect.Height = Mainpanel.Height;
rect.Width = Mainpanel.Width;
rect.X = 0;
rect.Y = 0;
memoryImage = new Bitmap(Mainpanel.Width, Mainpanel.Height);
Mainpanel.DrawToBitmap(memoryImage, rect);
pictureBoxMiniature.Image = memoryImage;
```

Comment: Проходитесь по всем контролам в коллекции `Controls` и вызываете у них `DrawToBtimap`, а также рекурсивно проходитесь по их коллекциям `Controls`

Comment: Увеличьте размер панели так, чтобы все элементы были видны на скриншоте, а за тем можно уменьшить ее обратно)

Answer (score 1):

У всех контролов есть функция DrawToBitmap()

Если предположить, что у тебя панель меньше размера содержимого(и у тебя есть полоса прокрутки). Тогда ты меняешь на 1 секунду размер панели до размера содержимого, делаешь скриншот, а потом возвращаешь размер панели назад:

```
    public Bitmap GetControlScreenshot(Control control)
    {
        Size szCurrent = control.Size;
        control.AutoSize = true;

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height);//создаем картинку нужных размеров
        control.DrawToBitmap(bmp, control.ClientRectangle);//копируем изображение нужного контрола в bmp

        control.AutoSize = false;
        control.Size = szCurrent;

        return bmp;
    }
```

Если же панель не на столько большая, будет достаточно:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);//создаем картинку нужных размеров
panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, panel1.ClientRectangle);//копируем изображение нужного контрола в bmp
```

Собственно, если воспользоваться на родительском элементе, то он отрисует в битмап и все дочерние. И скриншотить ничего не нужно, оно захватит полностью контролы, даже, если в даную секунду на форме их не видно. (то есть часть контрола выходит ЗА рамки формы)

Вот пример окна:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот пример сделанного скриншота панели:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никаких мучений с рекурсией не нужно.

Upd:
Для скриншота всей формы и всех элементов на ней подход тот же(ведь, сама форма -- тот же контрол!):

```
   System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);//создаем картинку нужных размеров

   this.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));//копируем изображение нужного контрола в bmp

   bmp.Save("E:\\somePanelImage.bmp");    //ну и дальше просто сохраняем
```

UPD2: некоторые считают что таким макаром нельзя отскриншотить дочерние элементы. У этого растут ноги от того, что некоторые люди создают контролы програмно не задавая родительского элемента новому.

Что б проще: програмно создается новый элемент и размещается с абсолютными координатами формы НАД панелью. В таком случае, конечно же, панель будет отскриншочена этим методом пустой, ведь "дочерний" элемент не является дочерним в буквальном смысле. **Он находится просто НАД панелью и только лишь визуально выглядит дочерним контролом.**

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, пф, а как тогда я получила вторую прикрепленную картинку
? Вторая прикрепленная картинка именно то, что сохранила моя тестовая программа на МОЙ диск Е. На, держи еще один тестовый скриншот, мож тебе легче станет: http://prntscr.com/lpsbhe И прошу заметить что на изображении видно как календарь, так и текстовое поле, так и родительский Panel. Код просто скопипастила со своего же ответа, замечу.

Comment: Или  меня C# работает не так как у всех, а действует как то по-особенному и делает именно то, что я ожидала от этого кода. А у ты ожидал что заскриншотит только панель и у тебя скриншотит только панель. МАГИИИЯЯЯЯ -- никак иначе. Другого обьяснения у меня нету почему такой выпад был сделан в мою сторону :) И кстате, заметь, и в ответе и во прикрепленному к коментарию скриншоте остальные элементы на форме повторяются... Так что ВСЕ скриншоты и с самого начала были сделаны мной, как и код тестировался перед ответом.

Comment: почитай последние 2 абзаца ответа. Они для тебя :)

Comment: Ну значит магия -- другого обьяснения не имею. **У меня код работает** -- скриншоты прикреплены мои личные, в подтверждение что код рабочий. Скорее всего ты что-то намудрил в своем проэкте. У меня даже форма скриншотится по коду из ответа. **Со всеми дочерними контролами, замечу, а не пустая.** :) Выслать пример скриншота?) Или выложить проэкт с этим кодом из примера что бы ты запустил у себя?

Comment: Разобрался. Я вставлял код прямо в конструктор формы. Пока конструктор не отработал до конца, дочерние контролы не инициализированы, соответственно, отрисоваться не могут. В событии, `Shown`, например, тот же код отрисовывает и дочерние контролы.

Comment: Этот код - лишь слегка измененный код из вопроса. Он никак не решает проблему отображения элементов, выходящих за границы отображаемой в данный момент области панели.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight легкий фикс, хоть он и был описан текстово раньше, но если уж нужно и это было написать кодом... то пожалуста) Теперь делает скриншот и невидимой части [если контент панели больше самой панели].

Answer (score 0):

Можно временно увеличить размеры панели, так чтобы она захватывала все элементы, а после создания скриншота вернуть назад:

```
//сохраняем текущее положение полос прокрутки
int scrollx = -panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X;
int scrolly = -panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y;

Size szCurrent = panel1.Size; //сохраняем текущий размер панели
int xmax = panel1.Size.Width, ymax = panel1.Size.Height;

//сбрасываем полосы прокрутки в начало
panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(0, 0);           

try
{

    //найдем крайние координаты для элементов на панели
    foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (c.Right > xmax) xmax = c.Right;
        if (c.Bottom > ymax) ymax = c.Bottom;
    }

    //добавим запас на полосы прокрутки
    xmax += SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
    ymax += SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight;

    //временно увеличим размеры панели, так чтобы все элементы на ней уместились
    panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(xmax, ymax);                

    //создадим полный скришот панели 
    Bitmap memoryImage;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    rect.Height = ymax;
    rect.Width = xmax;
    rect.X = 0;
    rect.Y = 0;
    memoryImage = new Bitmap(xmax, ymax);
    panel1.DrawToBitmap(memoryImage, rect);
    pictureBox1.Image = memoryImage;
}
finally
{
    //возвращаем старый размер
    panel1.Size = szCurrent;

    //возвращаем старые позиции прокрутки
    panel1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(scrollx, scrolly);                

}
```